# how can i identify repeated values and create different column with python

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have this type of data I cant figure out how to identify and create different column

wind_speed
1.4
1.3
1.4
1.3
1.3
1.1
1.1
0.9
1.2
1.4
1
1.8
1.2
0.9
0.9
1.1
1.3
1.2
1.7
1.9
1.6
2.1
4.6
4.5
5.1
6.4
7.8
6.5
9.1
9.4
7.3
9.1
9
6.1

direction
W
WNW
WNW
NW
WNW
WNW
WNW
WNW
SW
WSW
S
SE
SSW
S
SSW
WSW
WSW
SSW
WSW
WSW
SW
SSE
SE
SE
SE
SE
SE
SE
SE
SE
SE
SE
SE
SE

for example SE is repeating more than 10 times above. i want to store wind speeds in SE directions repeated more than 10 times rows in a different variable, in python.

I tried to do watching some tutorials but i couldnt.

Any help will be nice!

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd

winds = pd.read_excel('datcawind.xlsx')

winds.drop_duplicates(['wind_speed','direction'],inplace=True)

Comment: Hello , not sure what you mean. Can you put an example of the output you would like to have as output result?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Paul this is a hourly wind data. i want to filter and see wind duration more than 10 rows. For example there is 12 rows with SE direction. I want to filter wind duration more than 10 rows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGViP.jpg)